# What do I have to do to set off the iPhone camera automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

I'm making an app that has to set off the camera. Does this have to be done with user interaction? Or can I just call a function? It seems like it has to be possible. It looks like Snapchat does it because it has it's own camera UI (FYI I'm using swift and am very new to iOS programming. I've been at it for about a week, but I have JS experience)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own Camera functionality from scratch using AVFoundation.  This is how apps like Snapchat work.

Start here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is Objective C code. Where do I place this code? And do I have to use all of this?